Weird behaviour in Lua string.gmatch
I would need to extract everything that comes before and everything that comes after the "\\scalebox" string. I tried with
local example = "sometext\\scalebox{0.74}"
for i in string.gmatch(example, "[^\\scalebox]+") do
  print(i)
end

I expect
sometext
{0.74}

but the result is
m
t
t
{0.74}

EDIT: not an escape chatacter problem, because
local example = "sometextscalebox{0.74}"
for i in string.gmatch(example, "[^scalebox]+") do
  print(i)
end

leads to same result
Any ideas?

[^\\scalebox] is a negated character class. You're telling Lua to match "one or more characters which are not in the set {, s, c, a, l, e, b, o, x}".

print( ("sometext\\scalebox{0.74}"):gsub("\\scalebox","") ) 

I'm assuming you've seen other posts that tell you to use [^sep] to split a string by the sep character. These work, but only for one character long separators.
So for your pattern, [^\\scalebox]+, we will split on ALL the characters \,s,c,a,l,e,b,o, or x. Which results in the list of strings that you're getting: "m", "t", "t", "{0.74}".
Since you want to split on text, rather than characters, you can use string.find to find the index of your "\scalebox", and then string.sub to substring around that index:
local s = "sometext\\scalebox{0.74}"
local pattern = "\\scalebox"

local index = s:find(pattern)
local first = s:sub(1, index - 1)
local second = s:sub(index + string.len(pattern), string.len(s))

This obviously can be made into a loop and be made to output as a table as needed, but you only mentioned needing the first/second halves.

Just capture anything that is before and after \\scalebox.
local pattern = "(.*)\\scalebox(.*)"

local text = "text before\\scaleboxtext after"

local before, after = text:match(pattern)

print(before)
print(after)

Please refer to the Lua manual. Square brackets define a character set. The pattern [xy] means any of ( x or y ). While ^ negates the set. So [^xy] means none of ( no x and no y ).
If you want to match a specific word you need to use the actual word.

I took a slightly different approach (as i was seeing same as you :-( )
cat user3204810.lua 
local instr = "sometext\\scalebox{0.74}"
local strip = "\\scalebox"

local res = string.gsub(instr, strip, "")

print( 'orig:', instr, " result:", res )

lua user3204810.lua 
orig:   sometext\scalebox{0.74}  result:    sometext{0.74}

as always, check/test/double-check all suggestions
